# How does Google domains resolve conflicting wildcard rules for email forwarding?

Tags: email, email-address, google-domains

I am using Google Domains for my website. I also get a free email-forwarding facility. However, there is no documentation on how the wildcard entries are resolved.

For example:
I have the following entries for email forwarding.

```
1. *      @example.com --> ex1@gmail.com
2. test*  @example.com --> ex2@gmail.com
3. test12*@example.com --> ex3@gmail.com
```

So, if I send test emails to

```
a. test123@example.com 
b. test1@example.com
c. anything@example.com
```

Which rule will be applied in each case?

My quick experiment suggests the rule #3, 2 and 1 is applied respectively. However, I am not sure if it is consistent i.e. will be applied consistently in the future. Is there a procedure that is used to resolve such conflicts/overlaps?

Comment: Does google domains even support partial wildcards? I've tried to use "part*@example.com" and matching emails (part123@example.com) are NOT going through.

Comment: I don't think partial wildcards are supported. only rule 1 will apply.

Answer (score 2):

At the time of writing, Google domains does not support partial wildcards for forwarding email addresses.

So if an email is an exact match of the the 2nd or 3rd email in your questions it will be forwarded to `ex2@gmail.com` and `ex3@gmail.com` respectively. All other emails will be forwarded to `ex1@gmail.com`.